# How can I add 2 buttons with shortcode

Tags: posts, shortcode

I want 2 buttons in my blog post. One is "DEMO" and another one is "DEWNLOAD" . For Demo button shortcode I use this codes.

```
function demo_button($atts,$content = null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'url' => '#'), $atts ) );
return '<a href="'.$url.'" class="btn btn-default btn-demo">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</a>';
}

add_shortcode('demo'.'demo_button')
```

It works fine in my site.. when I add download button in the same way the wordpress dashboard got white.Download button code

```
function download_button($atts, $content = null) {
 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'url' => '#'
), $atts ) );
return '<a href="'.$url.'" class="btn btn-default btn-download">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode('download', 'download_button');
```

I dont know Why.. I am new in wordpress and PHP.. SO please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I enter this shortcode:

```
[download url="http://example.com"]Download[/download]
```

it works fine. But you have to enter the link text as content yourself. You might have missed that, the way I read your question.

Your `[demo]`-Shortcode throughs an error. To see this, you need to have [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) set to true:

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: func in \wp-includes\shortcodes.php on line 92
```

This is because, your code says

```
add_shortcode('demo'.'demo_button');
```

This in fact creates an shortcode like `[demodemo_button]` with no function attached. Use a comma instead the point:

```
add_shortcode('demo','demo_button');
```

If you do so, it works fine too. But again, you have to add the link text as content, like here:

```
[demo url="http://example.com"]Linktext[/demo]
```

If you want a fixed link text, you should have a look into this code snippet:

```
function download_button($atts, $content = null) {
 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'url' => '#'
 ), $atts ) );
 return '<a href="'.$url.'" class="btn btn-default btn-download">Download</a>';
}
```